# how to add unsupported Patterns to an AutomationElement? do AutomationPeers change the application under test?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-ui-automation

the following custom control ToggleButton is not capable of InvokePattern.

```
<ToggleButton   Click="click_event" 
... />
```

What can I do to execute the **ToggleButton's click-event over some UIA-Pattern??**

---

This [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/172391/UIAutomation-Coded-UI-Tests-AutomationPeer-and-WPF) provides information about AutomationPeer & custom controls. But it seems like I need to change the application under test (AUT) to use this customized AutomationPeer?!
[Guideline if you are allowed to change the AUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc165614(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toggle buttons don't support [`InvokePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.invokepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but they do support [`TogglePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.togglepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You shouldn't need to dive into the automation peers at all.

Comment: You cannot use the TogglePattern in case someone implements a mouseover-/Click-event (or what ever other event) within a toggle-button. The TogglePattern would then try to access the Toggle-event, not the Click-Event...

Therefore afaik, a Provider becomes necessary as soon as another event, then the standard event gets implemented...

Comment: If the toggle button implements click, it should also implement InvokePattern.  That's what InvokePattern *means*.

Comment: thanks for your input, I do very much appreciate that! Could you please tell me if you are sure about that or if it is a guess? have you ever tested this issue before?

Comment: I'm quite sure about this.  (yes, this is a late response.)  The entire philosophy of UI Automation is that controls support the patterns describing their behavior.  The [Control Patterns for Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746719(v=vs.110).aspx) docs are explicit about this (particularly in the part titled 'Controls with Variable Patterns').

Comment: Sadly what you say seems not be true if controls gets manipulated, the UI Automation Provider does not get updated automatically. And afaik this has to be done inside of the application under test, and can't be done from outside :(

btw: I already statet in my initial post that invoke pattern is not available for this button, although it implements click-event

Comment: I think I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.  You've created a **custom control** using the WPF primitives in your app, and are wondering about automation.  For *any* custom control, you *have* to implement a custom automation peer.   You can build your peer out of the various peers for the primitives (as mentioned in the link in the question), but the peer must be built.

Comment: I have a `ToggleButton` with `Command="{x:Bind Command, ModeOneWay}"` which basically means it functions as a button, but UIA only exposes the `TogglePattern` (which does nothing). `Inspect.exe` clearly shows `IsInvokePatternAvailable: false`...

Comment: @OhadSchneider Of course it does.  If you misuse the tools, they don't work right.  More specifically - if you want a button, *use a button*.   Don't use a toggle that you've styled to look like a button.  Or, if you want a button that's styled to look like a toggle, *use a button*, and style it to look like a toggle.

Comment: Fair enough. So what did you mean when you said _If the toggle button implements click, it should also implement `InvokePattern`. That's what `InvokePattern` means_?  I took it to mean WPF would expose the `InvokePattern` in such a case for you, but I see that is not the case. Did you mean I can somehow add support for the `InvokePattern` without changing the control type? Just curious...

Comment: @OhadSchneider yes its possible to add the invokepattern without changing the control type.
Create a new class extending : ToggleButton and override the method "protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()" and return a self created AutomationPeer.
The AutomationPeer then extends ToggleButtonAutomationPeer and implements IInvokeProvider.
here is a guideline: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc165614(v=vs.100).aspx
btw: in my initial question I didn't want to change the application under test, but I also had pretty less knowledge about UIA back then :).

Comment: @Hansa thanks! I already got to that information, but it's a good thing you put it here for future readers. I thought Eric implied you could expose the pattern without extending the control, but it was probably just a misunderstanding on my part.